# Resetting the clipping region in DrawingContext

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am pushing several transformation matrices and clipping regions onto WPF's drawingContext object. I set clipping region to a smaller rectangle and after which I push several transformation matrices. Now I want to reset clipping region to an entire page. One possible option is to Pop() all the operations till the point where I pushed my smaller clipping region. But I have to retain all my matrices which I have pushed so far and also this a bit heavier process. And also I don't have separate Pop() methods for each of the push operations like PopClip() or PopTransformationMatrix() etc.

I would like to know what is the best way to achieve this. Is the Pop() is the only option to achieve this or is it possible mathematically to invert a Clip region?

Comment: Can't you just push another Clip region, or is it combined with previous ones?

Comment: Yes. If I push one more region it is intersecting with the previous one.